# Как узнать что число N больше числа N на 100 и более

Tags: python

Есть переменная `item_price` которая вытягивает цену предмета

так же есть переменная `save_price` которая сохраняет в себе значение последней цены. Цена в виде пятизначного числа + остаток

Как я могу измерить, поднялась ли новая цена `item_price` на 100 долларов больше последней сохраненной (`save_price`) ?

```
r = requests.get('https://')
    price = json.loads(r.text)

    item = price[:1]
    item_price = price[0]["price_usd"]
    save_price = item_price

return item_price
```

Comment: `if item_price >= save_price + 100:` - тот редкий случай, когда как думается, так и пишется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Путь тут как бы один:

```
if item_price - save_price >= 100:
```

Comment: Убрал комментарий, т.к. он никак не относится к ответу и не улучшает его

Comment: Принято, спасибо, по настоящему круто что тут есть такие модераторы